# Putting the same child component multiple times in the parent component does not render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, swiper.js

I have a parent component called **ParentComponent.vue**. In my case, I have another component called **ChildComponent.vue**. I intend to use the child component as many times as I want in the parent component. However, only one instance of **ChildComponent** is rendered and the rest doesn't render at all. When I inspect the elements in Developer tools, there are no trace of the subsequent child components. What am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.
In some instances the styles of the component  are not applied to the one that is shown.

**ParentComponent.vue**

```
<div>

<child-component></child-component>
<child-component></child-component>
<child-component></child-component>
 </div>
```

**ChildComponent.vue**

```
<template>
<div>
<p>The quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog</p>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
name: 'ChildComponent',
}
</script>
```

**EDIT**
I am using vuejs 2.6 and swiperjs 6.3 I created a component for swiper so that I could reuse it in my entire project.
Here is my swiper component

```
     <div class="swiper-container"
          >
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div v-for="(slide, index) in virtualData.slides"
                   :key="index"
                   :style="slideStyles"
                   class="swiper-slide"
              >
                <slot :index="swiper.activeIndex" :slide="slide"></slot>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

<script>
import Swiper from 'swiper/bundle';

export default {
  name: 'DefaultSwiper',
  data() {
    return {
      swiper: null,
      virtualData: {
        slides: [],
      },
    }
  },

  props: {
    slides: {
      type: [Array, Object, Number],
      required: true,
      default: function () {
        return []
      }
    },
    containerHeight: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: '500px'
    },
    containerWidth: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: '100%'
    },


    addOptions: {
      type: Object,
      required: false,
      default: function () {
        return {};
      }
    },

  },
  computed: {
    slideStyles() {
      return `left: ${this.virtualData.offset}px;`;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const self = this;

    this.swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', Object.assign({}, self.addOptions, {
      virtual: {
        slides: self.slides,
        renderExternal(data) {
          // assign virtual slides data
          self.virtualData = data;
        },
      },
    }));

    document.querySelector('.swiper-container').style.width = this.containerWidth
    document.querySelector('.swiper-container').style.height = this.containerHeight
 

  },

};
</script>
```

I will then use DefaultSwiper in the ParentComponent as follows

```
<template>
<div>
    <-! Works fine until I add the second one then slides will not show but the swiper container will be showing -->
<default-swiper 
    :slides="['Slide 1', 'Slide 2', 'Slide 3']" 
    v-slot:default="{slide}">
    <div>{{slide}}</div>
</default-swiper>
<-! other codes -->

<-! Doesn't work at all -->
<default-swiper 
    :slides="['path/to/img1', 'path/to/img2', 'path/to/img3']" 
    v-slot:default="{slide}"> 
    <img :src="slide" alt="Image" />
</default-swiper>
</div>
</template>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your code works for me. Can you post more of your ParentComponent.vue to show how you've imported the ChildComponent?

Comment: Hi it would be better if you could post more code. or you can take this code sandbox as a reference (assuming you are using Vue 2). https://codesandbox.io/s/parent-child-demo-vue2-tv9tr

Comment: I looked at the codesandbox code, tinkered with it and everything is working fine. It seems to me that the problem has to do with creating a wrapper for swiperjs. I will edit my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of repeating yourself"

```
<child-component v-for="i in 3" :key="i"></child-component>
```

and make sure you have imported the child component in parent component correctly

Comment: I appreciate your help. I am not using the child component all at once. They are used at different sections in the parent component.  I should have mentioned that.

Comment: fine, and make sure to import the child component and  also add components declaration like this 
  `components: {
    'child-component': ChildComponent
  }`